# change in a variable outside angular scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Beginner in Angular + looked at most of complex $watch, $digest and $apply threads around but I still can't make something work.

`var masterArray = [obj1, obj2, ... ];`

This variable is not inside any angular scope and on plain JS and gets updated by plain JS again outside angular's scope periodically by user's interactions.

How can we capture the change in the `masterArray`, and update the associated `$scope` as well.

```
  app.('mycontroller', ['$scope', function($scope){
        $scope.items = masterArray;
    }]);
```

Is there a way to update `$scope.items` with masterArray changes? This thing works only when I reload the page as `masterArray` is pushed to LocalStorage everytime it's updated.

Similar concern - my data variable (outside angular) arrives a little late with callback function from server in plain js or jquery but my angular scopes and variables are already defined during document load.

I couldn't find a way to update my angular scopes associated with those variables which during page load were null or empty are now updated with data.

Comment: Its is working fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/HB7LU/23477/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

some hack like this should work:

```
  app.('mycontroller', function($scope){
      $scope.items = masterArray;
      $scope.$watch(function() {
          return masterArray;
      }, function(masterArray) {
          $scope.items = masterArray;
      });
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I've been trying the `$watch()` as well but just wasn't adept enough, I guess.